# Simplest possible rack app -> permission error

Tags: ruby, rvm, rack

Here's the program(1.rb):

```
require 'rack'

my_rack = lambda { |env| [200, {}, ["Hello.  The time is: #{Time.now}"]] }
handler = Rack::Handler::WEBrick

handler.run(my_rack, :PORT => 12_500)
```

Here's the error:

```
~/ruby_programs$ ruby 1.rb 
[2012-12-07 21:49:09] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-12-07 21:49:09] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2012-12-07 21:49:09] WARN  TCPServer Error: Permission denied - bind(2)
[2012-12-07 21:49:09] WARN  TCPServer Error: Permission denied - bind(2)
/Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `new'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:85:in `block in create_listeners'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `each'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:82:in `create_listeners'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:82:in `listen'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:70:in `initialize'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:45:in `initialize'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@programming/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `new'
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@programming/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:10:in `run'
    from 1.rb:5:in `<main>'
~/ruby_programs$
```

Here's line 85 of ../webrick/utils.rb:

```
sock = TCPServer.new(ai[3], port)
```

If I replace the code in 1.rb with this:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 12_000 # Server bind to port 2000

loop do
  client = server.accept    # Wait for a client to connect
  client.puts "Hello !"
  client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
  client.close
end
```

I don't get any errors, and if I enter the address:

```
http://localhost:12000/
```

in my browser, I get the expected output:

```
Hello !
Time is 2012-12-07 18:58:15 -1000
```

The permissions for the .rvm directory:

```
~$ ls -al
total 208
...
drwxr-xr-x  30 7stud  staff   1020 Aug 31 11:09 .rvm
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option Port should be in PascalCase

```
require 'rack'

my_rack = lambda { |env| [200, {}, ["Hello.  The time is: #{Time.now}"]] }
handler = Rack::Handler::WEBrick

handler.run(my_rack, :Port => 12_500)
```

Comment: :PORT v. :Port. Aargh. Thanks!  I guess the script was trying to connect to port 80 by default, hence the error.